# Android service execution denied

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms, commonsware-cwac

I have a service implemented as a [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). It is started every time a proper intent is issued to the `BroadcastReceiver` responsible by starting it. The service starts in two situations: upon device boot and when a running instance of the service is about to finish and schedules a new execution by asking Android's conventional task scheduler, the `AlarmManager`, to issue a starter intent at a future time.

The question is, I [have been advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073938/android-service-scheduled-on-alarmmanager-not-starting) not to use `android:exported="true"` in the service declared in the Manifest file for security reasons. However, omitting it causes the service execution to be denied in one of the test phones (a Samsung S3 running Android 4.1.2):

```
06-13 11:34:34.181: W/ActivityManager(2270): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10155
06-13 11:34:34.181: W/ActivityManager(2270): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.MyService} from pid=10320, uid=2000 that is not exported from uid 10155
```

Adding `android:exported="true"` fixes the problem. Is there an alternative to avoid the execution denial without compromising the app's security?

The Manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.myapp"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mypackage.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.MyService"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, MyService.class);
    }
}
```

The service containing the starter intent scheduling code in `onDestroy()`:

```
public class MyService extends WakefulIntentService {

(...)

    @Override
    public void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        (...)
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.mypackage.myapp"), 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

        am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, ONE_MINUTE, pi);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense. Is this occurring from boot or from the `AlarmManager`? Any idea what the other process is (the one identified as `10155` in your error)? BTW, you don't need to use an action string for your `BroadcastReceiver` -- just use `new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class)`. Also, you don't need the category on the `BOOT_COMPLETED` `<intent-filter>`, as that is not used.

Comment: 10155 is the **UID** of the asker's app.  2000 is the UID of the attempting initiator, which sounds like a platform component and not some random app.

Comment: The android docs sure make it sound like the service would need to be exported, unless there's supposed to be some undocumented there exception for system origins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: But the system isn't talking to the service, any more than it talks to any other private service. Both `BOOT_COMPLETED` and the `AlarmManager` are talking to the *`BroadcastReceiver`*, not the service. If the `BroadcastReceiver` were not exported, I could definitely see an issue. But the `BroadcastReceiver` does not need the `Service` to be exported, since it is in the same app, and the `BroadcastReceiver` is exported by default, since it has an `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: From the logcat, something is clearly *trying* to talk to the service.  Perhaps there's a mistake in setup causing that to be attempted instead of the broadcast.

Comment: Maybe put some logging code in the broadcast receiver, ideally have it log its pid and uid.

Comment: FWIW, this sample app using `WakefulIntentService` ran just fine on an S3: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful Now, the "S3" is used for a fair number of distinct devices, so that may not mean much, but you might try running it on your S3 and see if you run into the same problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Actually it doesn't occur from boot but when I attempt to start it manually on `adb shell`: `am startservice com.mypackage.myapp/.MyService`. BTW, I haven't been able to make the service start upon boot after removing the action string in my `new Intent()`, even if I keep the `<intent-filter>` with the string in the Manifest. Removing the category from `BOOT_COMPLETED` was okay though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually it doesn't occur from boot but when I attempt to start it manually on adb shell: am startservice com.mypackage.myapp/.MyService.

Then don't do that. Your users won't be doing that. Exporting a service, just so you can run an `adb shell` command, is not an especially wise move. Moreover, you can test sending the boot-time broadcast from `adb shell`, achieve the same end, and not have to export the service.

> I haven't been able to make the service start upon boot after removing the action string in my new Intent()

Sorry, I meant your second action string. Your `<receiver>` should look like:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And the corresponding `PendingIntent` would be:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class), 0);
```

Comment: I don't like the idea either, but I haven't been able to have the service obey a boot-time broadcast without exporting the service. What could be the alternative in this case? Besides, I'm still trying to make your second suggested receiver setup to work. As a side note, I noticed that the `onDestroy()` method is not guaranteed to finish, so I no longer recommend scheduling the service execution there.

Comment: @Piovezan: "I haven't been able to have the service obey a boot-time broadcast without exporting the service" -- it works for every other developer. "Besides, I'm still trying to make your second suggested receiver setup to work" -- I already provided you with a link to a project that demonstrates this *and* the non-exported service (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful).

Comment: My apologies, I didn't pay attention to your link. Also your suggestion works, I was mistakenly calling the wrong class in my intent. The S3 device will not be available for a few days for testing, but I have already verified that your project works normally in it. I'm now putting my project side by side with yours to see the differences and what I'm missing. The only difference, though, seems to be the lack of category in the receiver declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same symptoms on KitKat (see this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=61850). You could try to see if changing your Intent's signature (e.g. action) makes a difference.